# Rmagick show image without write

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using Rails 5 and I'm creating images with Rmagick. I want to show these images in view without writing them, because it costs time processing. In my project, I don`t need to save these images.

I saw the property 'display' of rmagick, but I don`t want to open the image, just to show in the view, like render.

```
image = Magick::Image.read('URL').first
image.write()
```

So rather than write and display, I want to show the image in the view.

Answer (score 0):

You can view these by first using `image_read()` which will let you access the image object itself.